# Animation changing a HSL variable isn't working

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a rainbow animation with CSS variables and HSL. I've got the following code, however in Chrome it just snaps between both states.

```css
@keyframes rainbow {
    from {
        --accent-bright: hsl(0,87%,48%);
        --accent-dark: hsl(0,94%,48%);
        --accent-verydark: hsl(0,88%,33%);
    }
    to {
        --accent-bright: hsl(359,87%,48%);
        --accent-dark: hsl(359,94%,48%);
        --accent-verydark: hsl(359,88%,33%);
    }
}

.rainbow, .rainbow *, .rainbow > * {
    animation-name: rainbow;
    animation-duration: 3.6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

[...]

#topBar {
    height: 56px;
    width:100vw;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--accent-bright),var(--accent-dark));
    color: var(--text-onaccent);
}
```

If I change the hue in one of the keyframes to someething more noticible, you can see the gradient flipping.
[image: GIF of an gradient harshly flipping]

Comment: Do you have a reproduced snippets to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The property `background-image` is not *animatable***

However... `opacity` ***is*** *animatable*.

This means that you can create an `::after` pseudo-element, exactly overlapping your original element and animate the pseudo-element's `opacity` so that it fades into view.

Remember to apply `pointer-events: none` to the pseudo-element, so that, as far as interactivity goes, the pseudo-element remains entirely insubstantial.

---

**Working Example:**

**N.B.** I have introduced `yellow` to make the animation more visible.

```css
.rainbow {
  --accent-bright: hsl(0, 87%, 48%);
  --accent-dark: hsl(0, 94%, 48%);
  --accent-verydark: hsl(0, 88%, 33%);
  
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--accent-bright), var(--accent-dark));
    color: var(--text-onaccent);
}

.rainbow::after {
  --accent-bright: hsl(359, 87%, 48%);
  --accent-dark: yellow;
  --accent-verydark: hsl(359, 88%, 33%);

  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--accent-bright), var(--accent-dark));
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: rainbow 3.6s infinite;
}

@keyframes rainbow {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow"></div>
```